# What's the best way to convert from network bitcount to netmask?

Tags: networking, bit-manipulation

For example, if I have a network spec like 172.20.10.0/24, "24" is the bitcount. What's the best way to convert that to a netmask like 0xffffff00 ?

Comment: Do you mean pro grammatically, or on paper?  Little more detail will be helpful.

Comment: oops. I meant programmatically. In particular, I'm interested in doing it in Powershell. But interested in various approaches overall.

Comment: the two parts are called the prefix and suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why waste time with subtraction or ternary statements?

```
int suffix = 24;
int mask = 0xffffffff ^ 0xffffffff >> suffix;
```

If you know your integer is exactly 32 bits long then you only need to type 0xffffffff once.

```
int32_t mask = ~(0xffffffff >> suffix);
```

Both compile to the exact same assembly code.

Comment: However pay attention that shifting a 32 bit value b 32 bit positions is undefined in many assembly languages. However on a 64-bit machine this worked fine in Perl: `printf('%x', ~(0xffffffff >> 32) & 0xffffffff)`

Answer (score 7):

Assuming 32-bit mask and 32-bit int.

```
int keepBits = 24;  /* actually get it from somewhere else? */

int mask = (0xffffffff >> (32 - keepBits )) << (32 - keepBits);
```

Note: this isn't necessarily the answer to the question "What's the best way to get the network mask for an interface?"

Comment: Another one that assumes keepBits > 0.

Comment: Actually, I set keepBits equal to 24 so it is by definition > 0

Answer (score 4):

I always do it like that (in your case cidr = 24):

```
uint32_t ipv4Netmask;

ipv4Netmask = UINT32_MAX;
ipv4Netmask <<= 32 - cidr;
ipv4Netmask = htonl(ipv4Netmask);
```

This will only work with ipv4Netmask to be actually uint32_t, don't make it int, as int doesn't have to be 32 Bit on every system. The result is converted to network byte order, as that's what most system functions expect.

Note that this code will fail if `cidr` is zero as then the code would shift a 32 bit variable by 32 bit and, believe it or not, that is undefined behavior in C. One would expect the result to always be zero but the C standard says that this is not defined to begin with. If your CIDR can be zero (which would only be allowed in the any IP address placeholder 0.0.0.0/0), then the code must catch special case.

Comment: "the result is converted to network byte order" -- I think you intended to type htonl(ipv4Netmask)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a programming question, but in linux you can use whatmask.

```
whatmask 72.20.10.0/24
```

returns

```
IP Entered = ..................: 72.20.10.0
CIDR = ........................: /24
Netmask = .....................: 255.255.255.0
Netmask (hex) = ...............: 0xffffff00
Wildcard Bits = ...............: 0.0.0.255
------------------------------------------------
Network Address = .............: 72.20.10.0
Broadcast Address = ...........: 72.20.10.255
Usable IP Addresses = .........: 254
First Usable IP Address = .....: 72.20.10.1
Last Usable IP Address = ......: 72.20.10.254
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int keepbits = 24;
int mask = keepbits > 0 ? 0x00 - (1<<(32 - keepbits)) : 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: What if keepbits == 0? Watch out, those integer overflows will get you.

Comment: If keepbits is 0, then the '1' will shift all the way out of the register (assuming 32-bit register) and the netmask will be 0.  Isn't that the correct answer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Shifts_in_C.2C_C.2B.2B_and_Java says left-shift is undefined if an overflow occurs. MSVC and GCC both evaluate 1<<32 as 1, not 0.

Comment: int mask = keepbits > 0 ? 0x00 - (1<<(32 - keepbits)) : 0xFFFFFFFF;

Comment: You should declare mask as uint32_t.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in VBScript, FWIW

```
option explicit

'whatmask 72.20.10.0/24
If WScript.Arguments.Unnamed.Count < 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "WhatMask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xx"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

Dim sToFind
Dim aParts
Dim nSubnet

sToFind = WScript.Arguments(0)
aParts = Split( sToFind, "/", 2 )
nSubnet = aParts(1)

if nSubnet < 1 or nSubnet > 32 then
  WScript.echo "Subnet out of range [1..32]"
  Wscript.quit
end if

Dim sBinary
sBinary = String( nSubnet, "1")
sBinary = sBinary & String( 32 - nSubnet, "0" )

wscript.echo "0x" & lcase( binary2hexadecimal( sBinary ) )

function binary2hexadecimal( sBin )
  dim sSlice
  dim sResult
  dim i
  for i = 1 to len( sBin ) step 4
    sSlice = mid( sBin, i, 4 )
    sResult = sResult & hex( binary2decimal( sSlice ) )
  next
  binary2hexadecimal = sResult
end function

function binary2decimal( sFourbits )
  dim i
  dim bit
  dim nResult
  nResult = 0
  for i = 4 to 1 step -1
    bit = mid(sFourbits, i, 1 )
    nResult = nResult * 2 + bit
  next
  binary2decimal = nResult
end function
```

From the command line

```
>whatmask.vbs 123.12.123.17/23
 0xfffff700
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* C# version merging some of the other contributions and corrected for byte order. */

int cidr = 24;

var ipv4Netmask = 0xFFFFFFFF;

ipv4Netmask <<= 32 - cidr;

byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ipv4Netmask);

Array.Reverse(bytes);

ipv4Netmask = BitConverter.ToUInt32(bytes, 0);    

// mask is now ready for use such as:

var netmask = new IPAddress(ipv4Netmask);
```

Comment: This is what I needed, without reversing byte order you get the wrong mask e.g. CIDR prefix of 20 should be 255.255.240.0, not 255.255.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when you use the previous answers with code like:

```
0xFFFFFFFF << 32 - cidr
```

or

```
-1 << 32 - cidr
```

In C# at least, it will mask the shift count with 0x1F first. So, for a cidr with prefix 0 (ie the entire IPv4 address range):

```
int cidr=0;
0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - cidr) == 0xFFFFFFFF
```

which is not what you want. Instead, you should use:

```
int cidr=0;
(int)(0xFFFFFFFFL << (32 - cidr)) == 0
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something simple, like taking the bitcount and dividing by 4. That'd give you the leading F's in the mask. And then take the remainder and have a switch from 0 bits to 3 bits.