# How to convert CIDR to network and IP address range in C#?

Tags: c#, cidr

I have been looking around quite a bit to find some C# code to convert a network in CIDR notation (72.20.10.0/24) to an IP address range, without much luck. There are some threads about CIDR on stackoverlow, but none seems to have any C# code and cover exactly what I need. So I decided to cook it myself, and I did not want the code to rely on System.Net for any conversions in this version.

Perhaps it may be of help to someone.

References:

[What's the best way to convert from network bitcount to netmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218604/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-from-network-bitcount-to-netmask)

"Whatmask" C code from http://www.laffeycomputer.com/whatmask.html

Usage:

```
uint startIP, endIP;  
Network2IpRange("72.20.10.0/24", out startIP, out endIP);
```

The code assumes 32 bits for everything.

```cs
static void Network2IpRange(string sNetwork, out uint startIP, out uint endIP)
{           
    uint ip,        /* ip address */
        mask,       /* subnet mask */               
        broadcast,  /* Broadcast address */
        network;    /* Network address */

    int bits;               

    string[] elements = sNetwork.Split(new Char[] { '/' });         

    ip = IP2Int(elements[0]);
    bits = Convert.ToInt32(elements[1]);

    mask = ~(0xffffffff >> bits);

    network = ip & mask;
    broadcast = network + ~mask;

    usableIps = (bits >30)?0:(broadcast - network - 1); 

    if (usableIps <= 0)
    {
        startIP = endIP = 0; 
    }
    else
    {
        startIP = network + 1;              
        endIP = broadcast - 1;
    }
}

public static uint IP2Int(string IPNumber)
{
    uint ip = 0;
    string[] elements = IPNumber.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
    if (elements.Length==4)
    {
        ip  = Convert.ToUInt32(elements[0])<<24;
        ip += Convert.ToUInt32(elements[1])<<16;
        ip += Convert.ToUInt32(elements[2])<<8;
        ip += Convert.ToUInt32(elements[3]);
    }
    return ip;
}
```

Feel free to submit your improvements.

Answer (score 23):

I recommend to use the C# IPNetwork class from [Github](https://github.com/lduchosal/ipnetwork).

```
string net = "192.168.168.100/24";
IPNetwork ipnetwork = IPNetwork.Parse(net);

Console.WriteLine("Network : {0}", ipnetwork.Network);
Console.WriteLine("Netmask : {0}", ipnetwork.Netmask);
Console.WriteLine("Broadcast : {0}", ipnetwork.Broadcast);
Console.WriteLine("FirstUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.FirstUsable);
Console.WriteLine("LastUsable : {0}", ipnetwork.LastUsable);
Console.WriteLine("Usable : {0}", ipnetwork.Usable);
Console.WriteLine("Cidr : {0}", ipnetwork.Cidr);
```

It will ouput

```
Network : 192.168.168.0
Netmask : 255.255.255.0
Broadcast : 192.168.168.255
FirstUsable : 192.168.168.1
LastUsable : 192.168.168.254
Usable : 254 
Cidr : 24
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how you do it for your example `72.20.10.0/24`,

Let `Network` be `72.20.10.0`
`Mask` is `~((1 << (32-24)) - 1)` // or
`Mask` is `~(0xFFFFFFFF >> 24)`

- which is `0xFFFFFF00`

**StartIP** is -- `(Network & Mask)`;

- which is `72.20.10.0 & 0xFFFFFF00`

**EndIP** is -- `((Network & Mask) | ~Mask)`;

- which is `(72.20.10.0 & 0xFFFFFF00) | 0x000000FF`

This will be `72.20.10.0 -- 72.20.10.255`.

Answer (score 5):

The steps would go like this for a `network/maskBits`,

You compute the `mask` in one of these two ways,

```
mask = ~((1 << (32 - maskBits)) - 1) // or,
mask = ~(0xFFFFFFFF >> maskBits)
```

then the range is,

```
StartIP = network 
EndIP   = network | ~mask
```

More precisely,

```
StartIP = network & mask
EndIP   = (network & mask) | ~mask
```

Where,

- `<<` is bitwise left shift (without rollover)
- `&` is bitwise AND,
- `|` is bitwise OR, and
- `~` is bitwise INVERT.

Comment: `mask = ~(0xFFFFFFFF >> maskBits)` will not produce the correct value when `maskBits` is 32 - the value will be 0x0 instead of 0xFFFFFFFF

Comment: Actually I didn't get either of these methods to work. `~(0xFFFFFFFF >> 24)` returns `0.255.255.255` instead of `255.255.255.0`. What did work for me was: `0xFFFFFFFF >> -24`

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to convert CIDR notation to a range in T-SQL, [from my blog post](http://bitmugger.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-convert-cidr-ip-address-to-range.html) :

> First pre-create this function in SQL Server (from
>   http://www.stardeveloper.com).

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertIPToLong](@IP varchar(15))
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Long bigint
    SET @Long = CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 4)) * 256 * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 3)) * 256 * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 2)) * 256 +
        CONVERT(bigint, PARSENAME(@IP, 1))

    RETURN (@Long)
END
```

> This is a sample of T-SQL code I put together that will calculate the
>   low and high IP ranges from a CIDR address. It's messy and I had to
>   work around T-SQL's lack of bit shift operators.

```
Declare @CidrIP varchar(50)
Set @CidrIP = '10.100.60.55/28'

Select dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) as LowRange,
       dbo.[ConvertIPToLong](left(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) - 1)) & (cast(4294967295 as bigint) ^ (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)) + (Power(2, 32 - Cast(substring(@CidrIP, patindex('%/%' , @CidrIP) + 1, 2) as int)) - 1)
```