# IPv4 prefix length to netmask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ipv4

One option for the conversion would probably be:

```
IN_ADDR NetMask;
NetMask.S_un.S_addr = PrefixLength ? (0xFFFFFFFF >> (32 - PrefixLength)) : 0;
```

but is there a more standard/portable way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

This will not work for a prefix length that is not a power of 8.  Consider a length of 20, you want 0xF0FFFF (network order).  That means you'll want to do something like this:

```
PrefixLength ? htonl(~((1 << (32 - PrefixLength)) - 1)) : 0
```

Or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/218748/601004).  But you will need a htonl call or something more complicated than a simple shift to get a netmask in network order.

Answer (score 0):

That's fine, as long as you make the constant *unsigned* so the right shift is well-defined:

```
NetMask.S_un.S_addr = PrefixLength ? (0xFFFFFFFFu >> (32 - PrefixLength)) : 0;
```

Comment: Won't `0xFFFFFFFF` already be `unsigned` (based on the table in 6.4.4 of C99)?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good question. I only have access to the draft right now, and the table there says that the type is the first of the corresponding list in which the value can be represented, and it starts with `int` (even for hex literals). `0xffffffff` is representable as `int`, isn't it?

Comment: My interpretation is that hex constants are inherently positive; so `0xffffffff` is equal to `+4294967295`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, literal decimal, octal, and hex constants are *`signed int`* unless indicated by a suffix.

Comment: @vonbrand: That's true for decimal, but not for oct/hex, according to the table in the standard ;)